# Makefile rule "foo : bar : baz"

Tags: makefile, prerequisites

What does it mean to have a rule specified as follows?

```
foo: bar : baz
```

I understand that `foo` is a target, `bar` and `baz` are prerequisites but why there is another colon between `bar` and `baz` - what's the meaning of that colon?

Comment: Does it really say `:` there, and not `|`? If so, which make dialect is this? GNU make rejects it.

Comment: @hvd GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

Comment: Huh. I tried it with "GNU Make 4.0 Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu", and I get "Makefile:1: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature you are thinking of is a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html), and the syntax you give: `foo : bar : baz` is illegal; the `bar` part *must* be a *pattern* (that is, it must contain a `%` character).

Tripleee gives a reasonable explanation, except the statement *when we build `foo`, `bar` depends on `baz`* is somewhat confusing.  What a static pattern rule means is that for each word in *targets*, create a new explicit rule where the target is the result of applying the pattern *pattern* to that word with the prerequisites *prerequisites*.

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax is

```
targets: pattern: prerequisites
```

So this -- grossly oversimplified -- example of yours says, basically, when we build `foo`, `bar` depends on `baz`. However, the second argument needs to be a pattern rule, so your example is in fact a syntax error.

A more useful and correct example would be along the lines of

```
$(OBJS): %.o: ick.h
```

which says that if you are building one of `OBJS`, their `.o` file depends on `ick.h`.

Comment: _when we build `foo`, `bar` depends on `baz`_ is not right.  The important thing to realize is that the question is totally wrong: as hvd says above it's a syntax error to use `foo : bar : baz`.  The `bar` word _must_ be a _pattern_, and the pattern _must_ match each word in the `foo` section.  What this means is, "for each word in the `foo` section, create a new rule where the target is the result of applying the pattern `bar` to each word and the prerequisites are `baz`".

Comment: @MadScientist Please move your comment to a new answer.